# Javascript - can't iterate over object in incremental search

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to javascript/dev so I hope there is a an obvious solution that I've not thought of.  My code returns search items from TVMaze.com API.  The feature giving me trouble is the incremental search (as a user types in input box, the code returns and displays images by creating a new div and appending images, removing and replacing the an div).

My problem is that on deleting all characters from input box, I receive the error: "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: shows is not iterable" which I suppose means that there is no object to iterate over? Thanks in advance for any help.

```
const input = document.querySelector("#query");
input.addEventListener("input", async function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const searchTerm = e.target.value;
    const config = { params: { q: searchTerm } };
    const res = await axios.get(`http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?`, config);
    makeImages(res.data);
    clearList();
});

const makeImages = (shows) => {
    const div = document.createElement("div");

    for (let result of shows) {
        if (result.show.image) {
            const img = document.createElement("IMG");
            img.className += "resultImage";
            img.src = result.show.image.medium;
            const title = document.createElement("h3");
            title.className += "resultTitle";
            title.innerText = result.show.name;
            const year = document.createElement("h4");
            year.className += "score";
            year.innerText = result.show.premiered;
            var sub = year.innerText.substring(0, 4);

            var yearNum = parseInt(sub);

            div.append(year);
            div.append(img);
            div.append(title);
            document.body.appendChild(div);
        }
        if (yearNum <= 2000) {
            var retro = document.createElement("h5");
            retro.className = "retro";
            retro.innerText = "retro";

            div.append(retro);
        }
    }
};

let clearList = () => {
    var allImg = document.querySelectorAll("IMG");
    if (allImg.length === 0) {
        document.createElement("div");

        return makeImages();
    }
    var oldDiv = document.querySelector("div");
    oldDiv.remove();
    console.log(oldDiv);
};
```

Comment: `return makeImages();` You are effectively passing `undefined` to `shows`, which is not iteratable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Can you be more specific?  I have removed return makeImages() in clearList function as I realised that might be redundant(?)  I understand (from your comment) that I  was passing undefined to makeImages but I still can't see what the solution is.